# where we get the source of K9 email client for android?

Tags: android

K9 mail client is open source android application. Where can we get the source files ?

Answer (score 1):

From the [source checkout page](http://code.google.com/p/k9mail/source/checkout) in the [Google Code project](http://code.google.com/p/k9mail):

```
# Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.
svn checkout http://k9mail.googlecode.com/svn/k9mail/trunk/ k9mail-read-only
```